# Flat XML into tree with XSLT. Show one branch only

Tags: xslt

I have flat xml structure, i need to convert into hierarchy. With the help of stackoverflow I was able to do it. 
Question: Is it possible to show only one branch using the same flat structure?

Here is my xml and xsl files:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Stack.xsl"?>
<Items>
    <Item>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <ParentId>0</ParentId>
        <Name>1</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <ParentId>1</ParentId>
        <Name>1.1</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <ParentId>1</ParentId>
        <Name>1.2</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <ParentId>1</ParentId>
        <Name>1.3</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>5</Id>
        <ParentId>1</ParentId>
        <Name>1.4</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>6</Id>
        <ParentId>0</ParentId>
        <Name>2</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>7</Id>
        <ParentId>6</ParentId>
        <Name>2.1</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>8</Id>
        <ParentId>6</ParentId>
        <Name>2.2</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>9</Id>
        <ParentId>0</ParentId>
        <Name>3</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <ParentId>3</ParentId>
        <Name>1.2.1</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>11</Id>
        <ParentId>8</ParentId>
        <Name>2.2.1</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Id>11</Id>
        <ParentId>5</ParentId>
        <Name>1.4.1</Name>
        <SortOrder>0</SortOrder>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <xsl:param name="SelectedId" select="'10'"/>
    <xsl:key name="ChildNodes" match="/Items/Item" use="ParentId"/>

    <xsl:template match="Items">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[ParentId = 0]" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <li>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Id = $SelectedId">
                    <b><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></b>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:variable name="Descendants" select="key ('ChildNodes', Id)" />

            <xsl:if test="count ($Descendants) > 0">
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$Descendants" />
                </ul>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output I have:

```
1
   1.1
   1.2
        1.2.1
   1.3
   1.4
        1.4.1
2
   2.1
   2.2
        2.2.1
3
```

Desireable result example:

```
1
   1.1
   1.2
        1.2.1
   1.3
   1.4
2
3
```

Comment: Please explain whether you want the child and descendants of the second and third branch to be hidden when the transformation result is rendered in the browser or whether you want the XSLT not to generate them at all.

Comment: I want XSLT not to generate them. Something like this `<xsl:if test="count ($Descendants) > 0 and (Id = $SelectedId or $Descendants[Id = $SelectedId])">` but it works only for first two levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to make use of node-set function, which will require the use of an extension namespace in XSLT.

What you could do is that instead of outputing the **Descendants** variable directly as currently:

```
<ul>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$Descendants"/>
</ul>
```

You instead store the results in a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="list">
   <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$Descendants"/>
   </ul>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then you can convert this 'result tree fragment' into a node-set, which you can then check for whether the selected element (held in a **b** element) exists. If so, you can then output it

```
<xsl:if test="exsl:node-set($list)//li[b]">
   <xsl:copy-of select="$list"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:exsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
 exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
   <xsl:output method="html"/>
   <xsl:param name="SelectedId" select="'10'"/>
   <xsl:key name="ChildNodes" match="/Items/Item" use="ParentId"/>

   <xsl:template match="Items">
      <ul>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[ParentId = 0]"/>
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Item">
      <li>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Id = $SelectedId">
               <b>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
               </b>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
         <xsl:variable name="Descendants" select="key ('ChildNodes', Id)"/>
         <xsl:if test="count ($Descendants) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:variable name="list">
               <ul>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="$Descendants"/>
               </ul>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="exsl:node-set($list)//li[b]">
               <xsl:copy-of select="$list"/>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:if>
      </li>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<ul>
   <li>1
      <ul>
         <li>1.1</li>
         <li>1.2
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <b>1.2.1</b>
               </li>
            </ul></li>
         <li>1.3</li>
         <li>1.4</li>
      </ul></li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Note, because I am using Microsoft XML here, the extension namespace is "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt". For other processors, you will probably have to use "http://exslt.org/common"

Comment: Tim C, thank You very much! I'm new to XSLT, didn't know I can use such construction
`<xsl:variable name="list">
   <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$Descendants"/>
   </ul>
</xsl:variable>`
and didn't used exsl so far.